# Delaying a right click

Tags: catalina, mouse

I'm not sure why, but, every few minutes, my middle finger twitches enough to press the right mouse button. I might schedule an appointment with my doctor to check out what's be going on (e.g. lack of good sleep, caffeine, or something else), but, in the interim:

I've got a Logitech mouse with a few side buttons

- Is there a way of delaying the right click? Maybe to something like a second?
- Is there a way of mapping the right click to another button on the mouse?

Comment: Delaying tactic needing no system tweak. Put your ring finger on the right button & move your middle finger to the left… then book a doctor's appointment.

Comment: I was trying a combination of Logitech Options, Karabiner Elements, and BTT. It seems like it's almost possible using Karabiner and BTT, but sadly BTT doesn't have a "trigger when held down" option for key shortcuts... unless I'm missing something